# Android studio unable to recognize newly created drawable resources

Tags: android, android-studio

After creating new .xml resource file under drawable folder in Android Studio I'm unable to use it from any xml layout. It means when I'm starting to type its name - it won't appear in suggestions (whereas some other resources do). When I type it's complete name it won't turn red with "Cannot resolve symbol message", although won't appear in layout editor or in the app either.

The problem seems to be project specific, another project running on the same computer doesn't have such a problem.
Cleaning, Rebuilding, Cache Invalidation and restart don't have effect. Event log doesn't show any errors or warnings.

Can sombody suggest me something on this?

**Update**
[image]

Here's bg_test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
        android:top="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:right="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:bottom="@dimen/spacing_small" />
</shape>
```

But I think it has something to do with configuration of the project. So I can post buld gradle if needed.

Comment: you have 415 repute so you should understand how to ask. please provide code

Comment: update android studio, it fix

Comment: you must be using drawable v-21 or something hdpi ... change it to drawable

Comment: Android Studio is up to date.

Comment: As you can see in update the new file is under drawable folder

Comment: Only after reimporting project problem seems to have gone